# How to retrieve event log other than Application category?

Tags: c#, event-log

I'm trying to retrieve some event log in a category that is different from Application. For example, I want to get the info in "Microsoft-Windows-Application Server-Applications/Operational". Below it is my code

```
EventLog log = new EventLog("Microsoft-Windows-Application Server-Applications/Operational");
int index = log.Entries.Count - 1;
Debug.WriteLine(log.Entries[index].Message);
```

But it always shows the error:

```
The event log 'Microsoft-Windows-Application Server-Applications/Operational' on computer '.' does not exist.
```

If I simply use "Application", then I can get the log in Application category.

How to get log for "Microsoft-Windows-Application Server-Applications/Operational"?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `EventLog` class only lets you access Windows event logs.  You will want to use instead the `EventLogReader` found in `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader` namespace.

```
        EventLogQuery query = new EventLogQuery("Microsoft-Windows-Application Server-Applications/Operational", PathType.LogName, "*");
        EventLogReader reader = new EventLogReader(query);
        EventRecord eventRecord;
        while ((eventRecord = reader.ReadEvent()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}",
                eventRecord.TimeCreated,
                eventRecord.FormatDescription()));
        }
```

Comment: That is probably not true about accessing only the Windows event logs. On loading EventLog.GetEventLogs(), it does show a few logs from Applications and Service Logs

Comment: Source: MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog
"EventLog lets you access or customize Windows event logs."

Comment: That page needs more definition of what a 'Windows event log' is :) Never mind though, was just curious.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the `EventLogReader` and `EventLogQuery` to achieve this.

```
EventLogReader reader = new EventLogReader("Microsoft-Windows-Application Server-Applications/Operational");
string message = reader.ReadEvent().FormatDescription();
```

You can use the EventLogQuery to retrieve results in a descending order.

However, I am not too sure, why this does not work with the EventLog. Maybe somebody else can help clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

@MatthewG 's Answer is partly correct. `EventLog` class allows you to access administrative logs as per definition in MSDN. But they actually display folder names which are found under the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\`

You can verify this by creating a new folder with the a random name and you'll find the random name being displayed when you query using `EventLog.GetEventLogs()` method. Something, I believe that `Microsoft` have implemented very poorly.

So you're going to have to use `EventLogQuery` and `EventLogReader` classes to read event logs.