# Reading Applications and services log

Tags: vb.net, operating-system, event-log

I want to read a custom event log which is stored under Applications and services log section in Windows Eventlog.

Unfortunately when calling the Log according to its naming properties I receive an error message that the log cannot be found.

Ulitmately I try read event details from events with a specific ID but first I need to able to access the log.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim query As New EventLog("Logname as per Properties", System.Environment.MachineName)
        Dim elEventEntry As System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry

        Dim nmbr As Integer = query.Entries.Count

        MsgBox(nmbr)

    End Sub
End Class
```

This is the structure in the eventlog (I want to read the blue highlighted part)

[image]

Anybody any idea how to determine the correct log name?

Thx & BR
Daniel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve event log other than Application category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680388/how-to-retrieve-event-log-other-than-application-category) Also, [How to: Access and Read Event Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb671197(v=vs.90)) could be useful, although the VB.NET code example hasn't been fully translated to VB.NET.

Comment: (And the query would be `*[System/EventID=1]` or whatever other event ID you need.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you very much for that information! Despite searching it did not come up with that info. Do I get it right that i first need to open the eventlog with EventLogReader and I then subsequently filter by using EventLogQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many of the event logs, you need to use an [`EventLogQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogquery).

As an example, if you wanted to query the "Setup" event log to count the number of entries with an EventID of 1, you could do this:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim query As New EventLogQuery("Setup", PathType.LogName, "*[System/EventID=1]")
        Dim nEvents = 0

        Using logReader = New EventLogReader(query)
            Dim eventInstance As EventRecord = logReader.ReadEvent()
            While Not eventInstance Is Nothing
                nEvents += 1
                eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent()
            End While

        End Using

        Console.WriteLine(nEvents)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

You can see the names of the items to query by looking at the XML for an event in Windows Event Viewer.

The [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) construct makes sure that the `EventLogReader` is properly disposed of after it's been used.

Further information: [How to: Access and Read Event Information (from Microsoft)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb671197(v=vs.90)).